# Trying to make branch lines with css

Tags: css, line, branch

i'm trying to make a page that allows the user to create branches for incomes and outcomes, but i'm having a bit of a challenge creating the branch lines using CSS. What i did is create a div with 2 borders and position absolute.
The page generates infinite account cards using ngfor.

The branch lines should all connect to it's parent branch.

The code i wrote:

```
`<div [@showLine] *ngIf="line.Expanded">
    <div [@showLine] class="subAccount" *ngFor="let account of line.subAccounts; let i = index">
        <div class="setBorder"></div>
        <app-laccount-line [line]="account" (deleteAccount)="removeSubAccount($event)"      (enableDRE)="enableDRECompositive()" style="width: 97%; z-index: 2;"></app-laccount-line>
    </div>
</div>`

`.setBorder{
  border-left: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
  width: 2%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0rem;
  top: -1.5rem;
  z-index: 1;
 }`
```

This is the result so far:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHUPI.png)

Is there a way to do it with CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do it with the below CSS

```
<div [@showLine] *ngIf="line.Expanded" class="lineExpand">
    <div [@showLine] class="subAccount" *ngFor="let account of line.subAccounts; let i = index">
        <div class="setBorder"></div>
        <app-laccount-line [line]="account" (deleteAccount)="removeSubAccount($event)" (enableDRE)="enableDRECompositive()" style="width: 97%; z-index: 2;"></app-laccount-line>
    </div>
</div>



.setBorder{    
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
  width: 2%;
  height: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0rem;
  top: 1.5rem;
  z-index: 1;
}

.lineExpand:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1.5rem;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
  border-left: 1px solid lightgray;
}
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9X4i.png)